How to use twocolumn and singlecolumn in the same page
I am trying to get a single column abstract and a two column Introduction on the same page in an article document class.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\title{This is a test document}
\author{Holmes M. \and Holmes S.}
\date{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[5]
\end{abstract}
\twocolumn
\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

This generates two pages as shown in the figure even though I never used a \newpage command:

I tried to add the line \let\newpage\relax in the line between \end{abstract} and \twocolumn, but then the title page disappears and I only have the Introduction section.
Is there a way without the use of the multicol package to achieve this?


\twocolumn has an optional argument that takes an initial spanning text.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\title{This is a test document}
\author{Holmes M. \and Holmes S.}
\date{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[5]
\end{abstract}
\bigskip
}]

\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}

